# Why are Christian's children in "The Pilgrim's Progress" given Biblical names instead of character-based names?

Tags: name-significance, pilgrims-progress, john-bunyan

In *The Pilgrim's Progress*, virtually all of the characters are named after their character (e.g. Mr. Pliable, Mr. Honest, Mr. Worldly Wise-Man, Mercy, etc.). However, Christian's children all have Biblical names (e.g. Matthew, Joseph, Samuel). Why is this?